# How to get a list of all subfolders sorted by date?

Tags: windows, directory

Is there any way to do that? Maybe some external program?

```
dir "d:\Folder" /ad /b /o:-d /s
```

Sorting is not working with "/s" and folders for me.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Unix-Shells the Windows Command Line Interface isn't very powerful. Windows PowerShell might be better for you, if Windows is mandatory for you. See [this page](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/emulating-dir-command-powershell) for example.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an easy way to do this.
I just searched for "kind:folders" and sorted them by date.